# "Select count (*)" vs count of results from "Select 1" : which is more efficient way to get the rows count in DB2?

Tags: sql, performance, db2

I have two approaches to get count of rows in a table in DB2.
One way is

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Foo WHERE col1 = val1;
```

Another way is to count the results (number 1's list) which are retrived from following query with a method in my java code

```sql
SELECT 1 FROM Foo WHERE col1 = val1;
```

Here I will get the "list of number 1's" from second query and then get the size of that list in my java code to get count.

Can somebody explain which is most efficient way to get the rows count ?

Comment: second example does not give a count.  Are you perhaps confusing IF EXISTS () ??

Comment: @MitchWheat No. Actually I am trying to get list of 1's in my java code. And then I will get the size of that list.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based, but it stands to reason that generating a number will be more efficient than generating a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select count` is faster - because the database only needs to return a single number rather than a potentially long list.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mike. I am not aware of what kind of internal operation database will do. I am just trying to take the load off the database to check the count in my java code as I am just retrieving number 1's list only. please correct me if anything wrong.

Comment: The database has to do the same work of finding all the rows that match your criteria.  Then counting them is less work (just increment a counter) than creating a list of rows to return (allocate memory, initialize row structure).  Then the load of the network is less to send back a single number.

Comment: Also note that, depending on the criteria chosen, the db may not actually have to "count" the rows - if the criteria matches an index, the system can potentially retrieve it from stats, making it a single lookup.